# Prevent Mail.app from opening in split view

Tags: mail.app, mojave, catalina, fullscreen, split-view

After installing macOS Mojave, Mail.app always opens in split view when I am in a fullscreen space. Two examples:

1. I am in fullscreen Safari and click a mailto link: an email composition window opens in split view.
2. I am in any other fullscreen space and I click a notification of a new mail: the mail opens in split view.

Is there any way of preventing that from happening and instead opening Mail.app in a normal window?

Comment: Launch Mail independently from a non-fullscreen Space. Take it out of fullscreen, Quit. [Can't test as I don't have spilt view, but I'm guessing it's set to fullscreen, so wants to share]

Comment: @Tetsujin, no unfortunately this is independent of the view mode of Mail.app (I tested it just now once more to double check).

Comment: Ah, OK. Hope someone who uses split has an answer then.

Comment: Anyone have an answer to this question yet?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Mail -> Prefrences:

[image]

Then click on general and untick this box:

[image: image 2]

After unticking the box mail should return to its previous behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Daniil, I've seen this option before, but I don't think it's related to my question. This will open new messages in split view instead of an overlay window in full screen mode of Mail.app. So without Mail.app in full screen, this option has no effect. My case is independent of Mail.app being in full screen or not.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I know of is to minimize the mail window.  The issue appears to happen when Mail determines there is a problem getting mail from an account which happens often (for some reason) if you've got a lot of mail accounts.  If mail detects an issue, it pulls Mail to the front and if you're in full screen it puts it in split view when the system can get mail again.

If Mail is minimized to the dock it appears to not do this.

I have yet to find a way to disable split screen across the board (I would like to, as I never use it).