# Can't connect to Internet except via a VPN

Tags: network, wifi, vpn, internet, ethernet

A couple days ago all of a sudden my laptop stopped connecting to the Internet. For instance, if I open the Chrome browser (64-bit version 78.0.3904.97) and enter in the url textbox: `apple.stackexchange.com`,
then after a long wait the following message appears:

> This site can't be reached
>   apple.stackexchangecom's server IP address could not be found.
>   Try:
>   Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
>   DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

This happens whether I connect with Ethernet or WiFi.

However, strangely, my VPN app (TorGuard v. 3.96.1) still manages to connect when turned on, and if I repeat the above scenario while the VPN app is on, Chrome downloads the apple.stackexchange.com front page.

Given the above error message, I should probably add that, as far as I know, I use no proxy or firewall, however if someone could explain to me how to check this definitively, I'll be grateful.

**Computer**: MacBook Pro (mid 2012)
**OS**: macOS Catalina, v. 10.15

---

It has been suggested that this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177873). I don't think it is, becaused the other question says: "I just tried at a friend's house to check, with no problems." In my case I don't think trying to connect elsewhere would have solved the problem, because the problem was with the DNS settings, which, to the best of my understanding, are configured manually, and don't simply change by moving the device to another location (but I'm not sure).

Comment: Check your DNS and point it to 8.8.8.8 and alternate DNS server field, enter 8.8.4.4. And try to connect the internet without a VPN.

Comment: @Udhy: Could you please explain how to check my DNS and point it to these numbers?

Comment: Take the reference from here: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/enter-dns-and-search-domain-settings-on-mac-mh14127/mac ,remove with - if you have any DNS added already in the system.

Comment: @Udhy: Your solution works. Thanks! My guess is a couple days ago I didn't shut down the VPN app properly, so the DNS entries didn't revert to their original values as they should.

Comment: @Udhy: I'd like to add a variation of your solution, for future reference. Instead of using the DNS numbers you suggested, I looked up the DNS numbers used by my desktop computer (an iMac), and copied them.

Comment: @ankii: I'm not sure this is a duplicate, becaused the question you linked to says: "I just tried at a friend's house to check, with no problems." In my case I don't think trying to connect elsewhere would have solved the problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @EvanAad But  you can see excellent troubleshooting there and Udhy's recommendation is present there too, in multiple answers.

Comment: @ankii: Maybe so. Isn't it possible for two distinct problems to have the same solution?

Comment: It is definitely possible, but paraphrasing our mod bmike's comment: people can observe the same problem in different ways. Also, posting an answer instead of putting it up there as an edit,  would be helpful, as you have a catchy title in case someone searches it. I have neither any personal gain in voting for duplicates, nor any shame in having my [question closed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361383/mail-app-opens-randomly-in-macos-10-14-5).