# Disable window split on notification bubble click

Tags: notifications, catalina, fullscreen

When switching between a fullscreen app (terminal emulator) and another non-fullscreen app (Mail.app) by clicking on an email notification bubble, Mail.app opens as a split window. As a bonus, this messes up the layout on Mail.app so that I have to manually adjust it every time this happens.

Is there a way to disable that behavior, so that by clicking the notification bubble, the screen switches to the main Space and Mail.app is brought forward, like before this whole split screen thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mail app opens randomly in MacOS 10.14.5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361383/mail-app-opens-randomly-in-macos-10-14-5)

Comment: The question is actually a pretty close to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347416/prevent-mail-app-from-opening-in-split-view but not quite. My question is regarding what happens when I click on the notification bubble.

Comment: It’s the same setting regardless

Comment: Just tried it. Despite unchecking the option, a mail window still opens in split view on notification click.